# Testing if a prawn pdf was generated without errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, prawn, minitest

Using rails minitest and capybara how can I test if a pdf page was created without errors?  Im thinking checking the status_code is the easiest, but not sure if capybara supports this.

```
scenario "opens pdf without errors" do
  visit progress_report_path(format: 'pdf')
  page.must_have_status_code(200)
end
```

I know capybara doesn't have a "must_have_status_code" method...but, this illustrates what Im trying to accomplish.

How can I test the status code in rails minitest capybara?  Or, how can I test if a pdf page was generated by prawn without errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used this to test PDF downloads:

```
visit '/reports/summary.pdf'
page.status_code.must_equal 200
content_disposition = page.driver.response.headers['Content-Disposition']
content_disposition.must_include 'filename="summary.pdf"'

# the following assertions are mostly equivalent, pick what suits your style best
# I benchmarked them each 5 million times with a small pdf:
#   starts_with, ends_with: 0.000046
#   must_includes:          0.000080
#   regex                   0.000111
assert page.body.starts_with? "%PDF-1.4"
assert page.body.ends_with? "%EOF\n"

page.body.must_include '%PDF-1.4'
page.body.must_include '%EOF'

page.body.must_match /\A%PDF-1\.4.*%EOF\n\z/m
```